# Authetication fail on GDM

Tags: gnome, gdm

Sorry to Disturb you

We started having some issue during the authetication phase in ubuntu 18.04, mainly, but not limited to, trying to login after a locked session-

We are using an LPAD authentication and basically when we try to authenticate on GDM the systems says "Authentication Failed" ...the screen become blank, then reappear sometimes without the password field. Sometimes after several attempts, even the gnome freeze and we need to force a reboot.

This seems not happend using the local account, however the issue is only related the authentication on GDM because on the terminal (CTRL-ALT Fn) it works without issue.

What can be wrong on GDM? thanks in advance

Thanks A

Comment: Have you looked in your logs and the LDAP server logs? What do they say? Please add this information to your question.

Comment: I  cannot but i think is more related to GDM/Gnome like this post https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1628466